# How to do tasks by reading a string from left to right, and then do tasks assigned to each character?

Tags: java

I have a simple logical expression to english translator program that accepts inputs from the user (propositions and logical expression).

My problem is that I am clueless on how to check the logical expression so that if the string starts with p, the proposition "p" will be shown in the output, and then to proceed to check the next content of the string, and let's say it used the symbol "Λ", the word "and" should be displayed next.

**Image :**

[image: samplerun]

Once that is finished, one minor problem that I do not know to solve either is how to capitalize the first letter of the resulting translation, given that any of the the three propositions p, q, and r can come first depending on what the user inputs.

Edit: I added the code

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.JButton;

import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;

import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;

public class Dmep extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    JLabel Lp, Lq, Lr, Le, La;
    JTextField Tp, Tq, Tr, Te, Ta;
    JButton Bp, Bq, Br, Bnot, Band, Bor, Bxor, Bimp, Bico, Btl;

    Font font = new Font ("Calibri", Font.BOLD, 24);

    public Dmep()
    {
        Container C = getContentPane();
        C.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        C.setBackground(Color.green);

        Lp = new JLabel("Proposition p:             ");
        Lq = new JLabel("Proposition q:             ");
        Lr = new JLabel("Proposition r:             ");
        Le = new JLabel("Logical Expression: ");
        La = new JLabel("English Trasnlation: ");

        Tp = new JTextField("The window is open", 100);
        Tq = new JTextField("the program is running", 100);
        Tr = new JTextField("the translator will work", 100);
        Te = new JTextField("pΛqΛr", 100);
        Ta = new JTextField("The window is open and the program is running and the translator will work.", 100);

        Bp = new JButton("p");
        Bq = new JButton("q");
        Br = new JButton("r");
        Bnot = new JButton("¬");
        Band = new JButton("Λ");
        Bor = new JButton("V");
        Bxor = new JButton("⊕");
        Bimp = new JButton("→");
        Bico = new JButton("↔");
        Btl = new JButton("T R A N S L A T E");

        C.add(Lp);
        C.add(Tp);
        C.add(Lq);
        C.add(Tq);
        C.add(Lr);
        C.add(Tr);
        C.add(Le);
        C.add(Te);
        C.add(La);
        C.add(Ta);
        C.add(Bp);
        C.add(Bq);
        C.add(Br);
        C.add(Bnot);
        C.add(Band);
        C.add(Bor);
        C.add(Bxor);
        C.add(Bimp);
        C.add(Bico);
        C.add(Btl);
        Bp.addActionListener(this);
        Bq.addActionListener(this);
        Br.addActionListener(this);
        Bnot.addActionListener(this);
        Band.addActionListener(this);
        Bor.addActionListener(this);
        Bxor.addActionListener(this);
        Bimp.addActionListener(this);
        Bico.addActionListener(this);
        Btl.addActionListener(this);

        Ta.setEditable(false);

        setSize(1250,200);
        setTitle("Logical Expression to English Translator");
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        String pp, pq, pr, pa, pe;

        pp = Tp.getText();
        pq = Tq.getText();
        pr = Tr.getText();
        pe = Te.getText();
        pa = pp + pq + pr;

        if (e.getSource() == Bp)
        {
            Te.setText(String.valueOf(pe) + "p");
        }
        if (e.getSource() == Bq)
        {
            Te.setText(String.valueOf(pe) + "q");
        }
        if (e.getSource() == Br)
        {
            Te.setText(String.valueOf(pe) + "r");
        }
        if (e.getSource() == Bnot)
        {
            Te.setText(String.valueOf(pe) + "¬");
        }
        if (e.getSource() == Band)
        {
            Te.setText(String.valueOf(pe) + "Λ");
        }
        if (e.getSource() == Bor)
        {
            Te.setText(String.valueOf(pe) + "V");
        }
        if (e.getSource() == Bxor)
        {
            Te.setText(String.valueOf(pe) + "⊕");
        }
        if (e.getSource() == Bimp)
        {
            Te.setText(String.valueOf(pe) + "→");
        }
        if (e.getSource() == Bico)
        {
            Te.setText(String.valueOf(pe) + "↔");
        }
        if (e.getSource() == Btl)
        {
            Ta.setText(String.valueOf(pa) + "");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Dmep M = new Dmep();
        M.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
}
```

Comment: post the code.. we can propose something according to your logic/ algorithm

Comment: I have posted the code in my edit.

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to associate various strings to various characters. That's what a `Map<Character, String>` is for. If you don't know what a Map is, then read the [Java collections tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/), and the [javadoc of the Map interface](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).

Now, you has a String, which contains characters. By reading the [javadoc of String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html), you should be able to figure out how to loop through all the characters of that string. All you need now is to get the String corresponding to each character from the map, and join those strings together.

Here's a minimal example (but you could implement that in various other ways if you're not comfortable with streams and lamda expressions):

```
Map<Character, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put('a', "Hello");
map.put('b', "World");

String text = "abab";
String result = text.chars()
                    .mapToObj(i -> map.get((char) i))
                    .collect(Collectors.joining(" "));
System.out.println(result);
// prints Hello World Hello World
```